WPF Multibiding how to enter ElementName when the target element is in a different UserControl
In my WPF Window i have button with command
    <Button.CommandParameter>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{converters:Converter_MultipleCommandParameters}">
            <Binding ElementName="passwordBoxSQL" />
            <Binding ElementName="passwordBoxR2" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Button.CommandParameter>

and passwordbox with x:Name
        <PasswordBox
            x:Name="passwordBoxSQL"
            Grid.Row="4"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="0,0,10,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" />

It works well.
Then I moved Grid with passwordbox to another UserControl named Test in namespace XYZ.Control. In WPF windows i use
<Window
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XYZ.Control"

....
<local:Test />

After running the program, everything can be seen well, but there is an error:
XAML Binding Failures Description - Cannot find source: ElementName=passwordBoxSQL.
What should I give in Binding ElementName? Maybe it needs to be done somehow differently?

"What should I give in Binding ElementName?" - nothing. An ElementName Binding can only be used with elements in the same namescope. When you move the PasswordBox into a UserControl, it is no longer in the Window's namescope. It is unclear why you would use elements that are hidden in a UserControl in a Binding outside that control. That sounds wrong. But the UserControl may of course expose these elements as properties.

There's one / primary model / model view; and it should surface any secondary model / model views ... IMO. If there is no relationship, that begs the question: why?

I have many windows with a common part. I moved the common part to a separate one UserControl. The PasswordBox is in the common part and the button is not.
I have a VM for the common part. The VM for windows inherits from it.

I warn you right away that I agree with @Clemens that it is incorrect to search for an element by name inside a child UserControl. But for educational purposes I will show you a solution based on throwing the element name into the Window visibility area.
    public partial class TestUserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public TestUserControl1()
        {
            Loaded += OnLoaded;
            Unloaded += OnUnloaded;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window window = Window.GetWindow(this);
            window.UnregisterName(nameof(passwordBoxSQL));
        }

        private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window window = Window.GetWindow(this);
            window?.RegisterName(nameof(passwordBoxSQL), passwordBoxSQL);
        }
    }


I just have to compliment answering a question for informational and educational purposes even when the OP's approach to the problem might be flawed, rather than just giving the usual "you shouldn't be doing that" response.
